How to find NUL special character in a file using Spark
I have got characters in feed like 'NUL'. We are trying a to find a way through SparkSQL to find these records. We tried using \x00 etc as part of rlike etc, but spark dataset returned empty dataset

How we need to find these special characters using sparkSQL?
